# How to write an easy to expand set of color classes in C++

Tags: c++, templates, colors, embedded

### Background

I'm working with a number of different displays (hardware) and different canvases (is that the plural of canvas?). Each can work with different colors. Example cases:

1. RGB16 canvas -> RGB16 display (this is straight forward, but I didn't want exotic combinations only)
2. RGB16 canvas -> RGB24 display
3. Monochrome Canvas -> RGB16 display, where 'true' must show up as a color set at runtime.

At the moment I'm indeed working with the mono -> rgb16 combo (3) to have everything displayed in red and dimmable. Each display that might come might also have slightly different color types.

### What I'd like to have

I'd like to have an easy to expand set of color classes (C++). My goal is to be able to write simple assignments, as in

```
Monochrome m; // default value set at runtime
RGB556 rgb; // default value set at runtime

rgb = m; // conversion function known at compile time
```

and also

```
pixelBuffer<Monochrome,w*h> src;
pixelBuffer<RGB556,w*h> dest;

std::copy(src.begin(), src.end(), dest.begin());
```

This should be possible with templates. However, I'm not sure how to do that, and how I can keep the whole thing simple enough so that more color types can be added later without having to rewrite most of the code, but still being able to influence the details.

I'm sure it's possible to write a class template that takes a type and automagically offers conversion methods to 24-bit RGB, so that any color can be converted to that and then "down"-converted to anything smaller than that.

### What I've tried

Well, nothing specific, to be honest. I thought about using the CRTP to provide commonly used methods with compile-time inheritance, but I failed to come up with an implementation that compiles and does what I want. When I have something more I'll add it here.

Totally different approaches are also welcome as I haven't yet written code that uses a predefined interface that my color classes would have to provide.

---

### Experiment 1: Abstract interface vs direct assignment

As suggested in the comments and the first answer, I wrote a simple test to get a feeling for the timing. Here's my header:

```
#ifndef COLORS_H
#define COLORS_H

#include <stdint.h>

class Color
{
  public:
    virtual uint8_t r() const = 0;
    virtual uint8_t g() const = 0;
    virtual uint8_t b() const = 0;
    virtual void setR(uint8_t v) = 0;
    virtual void setG(uint8_t v) = 0;
    virtual void setB(uint8_t v) = 0;
    static uint32_t copies;
};

class RGB24 : public Color
{
  public:
    RGB24(uint8_t r = 0, uint8_t g = 0, uint8_t b = 0)
      : r_(r),
      g_(g),
      b_(b)
    {

    }
    uint8_t r() const {return r_;}
    uint8_t g() const {return g_;}
    uint8_t b() const {return b_;}
    void setR(uint8_t v) {r_ = v;}
    void setG(uint8_t v) {g_ = v;}
    void setB(uint8_t v) {b_ = v;}

    RGB24& operator=(const Color& other)
    {
      copies++;
      setR(other.r());
      setG(other.g());
      setB(other.b());
      return *this;
    }

    RGB24& operator=(bool b)
    {
      copies++;
      if (b)
      {
        setR(0xFF);
        setG(0xFF);
        setB(0xFF);
      }
      return *this;
    }

  private:
    uint8_t r_;
    uint8_t g_;
    uint8_t b_;
};

class Monochrome : public Color
{
  public:
    Monochrome(bool b = false)
      : b_(b)
    {

    }
    uint8_t r() const {return b_ ? 0xFF : 0;}
    uint8_t g() const {return b_ ? 0xFF : 0;}
    uint8_t b() const {return b_ ? 0xFF : 0;}
    void setR(uint8_t v) {b_ = (v != 0);}
    void setG(uint8_t v) {b_ = (v != 0);}
    void setB(uint8_t v) {b_ = (v != 0);}

    Monochrome& operator=(const Color& other)
    {
      setR(other.r());
      setG(other.g());
      setB(other.b());
      return *this;
    }

  private:
    bool b_;

};

#endif // COLORS_H
```

Here's the code I used to get some execution times (running on the target hardware, a Cortex-M4):

```
  RGB24 rgb[N];

  Monochrome m[N] = {true};
  elapsedMicros t;
  Serial.printf("Abstract Interface:\n");
  std::copy(m, &m[N], rgb);
  uint32_t us = t;
  Serial.printf("time = %u us\n", us);
  Serial.printf("rgb[N/2].r() = 0x%02x\n", rgb[N/2].r());
  Serial.printf("copies: %u\n\n", Color::copies);

  bool b[N] = {false};
  Serial.printf("Direct copy:");
  t = elapsedMicros();
  std::copy(b, &b[N], rgb);
  us = t;
  Serial.printf("time = %u us\n", us);
  Serial.printf("rgb[N/2].r() = 0x%02x\n", rgb[N/2].r());
  Serial.printf("copies: %u\n\n", Color::copies);
```

And the output:

```
Abstract Interface:
time = 1241 us
rgb[N/2].r() = 0x00
copies: 1000

Direct copy:
time = 157 us
rgb[N/2].r() = 0x00
copies: 2000
```

When I extrapolate the first number, 1241 microseconds, for a 128*128 display at 25 fps, just converting between the colors would take 50% of the CPU time. The calculation is: `128*128*25 pixels per second * 1241 us / 1000 pixels = 0.51 seconds`. A canvas/driver combo written for this situation can do it in about 0.1 seconds and it indeed has to copy and convert this many pixels per second because the whole display is drawn in every frame.

This comparison is probably a bit unfair, but bear with me. I'm not very experienced in profiling; and writing code that makes a fair comparison between what I have and what I'd like to have is simply not possible. The point is that Monochrome is essentially just a bool, and the compiler should be able to optimize for that when I have proper code.

---

### Experiment 2: Separate classes with a templated convert function

As André suggested, I wrote an RGB24 class, defined it as the `MostPreciseFormat`, and a templated free `convert` function. That said, I'm not sure if this is exactly what he meant:

```
class RGB24
{
  public:
    RGB24() : r_(0), g_(0), b_(0) {}
    uint8_t r_, g_, b_;

    uint8_t r() const {return r_;}
    uint8_t g() const {return g_;}
    uint8_t b() const {return b_;}

    void setR(const uint8_t& r) {r_ = r;}
    void setG(const uint8_t& g) {g_ = g;}
    void setB(const uint8_t& b) {b_ = b;}

    template<typename Other>
    RGB24(const Other& other)
    {
      convert(*this, other);
    }

    template <typename Other>
    RGB24& operator=(const Other& other)
    {
      convert(*this, other);
      return *this;
    }
};

typedef RGB24 MostPreciseFormat;

template <typename To, typename From>
void convert (To& to, const From& from)
{
//  Serial.println("Convert() called"); Serial.flush();
  MostPreciseFormat precise;
  precise.setR(from.r());
  precise.setG(from.g());
  precise.setB(from.b());
  to = precise;
}

template <>
void convert(RGB24& to, const bool& from)
{
  if (from)
  {
    to.setR(0xFF);
    to.setG(0xFF);
    to.setB(0xFF);
  }
  else
  {
    to.setR(0);
    to.setG(0);
    to.setB(0);
  }
}
```

This conversion needs 209 microseconds for 1000 pixels, which seems reasonable. But did I get it right?

---

### What I have now

This works as intended, based on Andrés answer. It has some issues, and probably needs some restructuring here and there. I have not yet looked at the CPU time it takes:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

namespace channel
{

static constexpr struct left_aligned_t {} left_aligned = left_aligned_t();
static constexpr struct right_aligned_t {} right_aligned = right_aligned_t();

template<typename T, unsigned int Offset_, unsigned int Width_>
class Proxy
{
  public:
    /* Some checks and typedefs */
    static_assert(std::is_unsigned<T>::value, "ChannelProxy: T must be an unsigned arithmetic type.");
    typedef T data_type;
    static constexpr unsigned int Width = Width_;
    static_assert(Width <= 8, "ChannelProxy: Width must be <= 8.");
    static constexpr unsigned int Offset = Offset_;
    static_assert((Offset + Width) <= 8*sizeof(T), "ChannelProxy: Channel is out of the data type's bounds. Check data type, offset and width.");

    Proxy(T& data) : data_(data) {}

    uint8_t read(right_aligned_t) const
    {
      return ((data_ & read_mask) >> Offset);
    }

    uint8_t read(left_aligned_t) const
    {
      return read(right_aligned) << (8-Width);
    }

    void write(const uint8_t& value, right_aligned_t)
    {
      // input data is right aligned
      data_ = (data_ & write_mask) | ((value & value_mask) << Offset);
    }

    void write(const uint8_t& value, left_aligned_t)
    {
      // input data is left aligned, so shift right to right align, then write
      write(value >> (8-Width), right_aligned);
    }

  private:
    static constexpr uint8_t value_mask = (uint8_t)((1<<Width)-1);
    static constexpr T read_mask = (value_mask << Offset);
    static constexpr T write_mask = (T)~read_mask;
    T& data_;
};

} // namespace channel

struct RGB24
{
  typedef channel::Proxy<uint8_t, 0, 8> proxy;
  typedef channel::Proxy<const uint8_t, 0, 8> const_proxy;

  RGB24() : r_(0), g_(0), b_(0) {}
  RGB24(const uint8_t& r, const uint8_t& g, const uint8_t& b)
    : r_(r), g_(g), b_(b) {}

  // unfortunately, we need different proxies for read and write access (data_type constness)
  const_proxy r() const {return const_proxy(r_);}
  proxy r() {return proxy(r_);}
  const_proxy g() const {return const_proxy(g_);}
  proxy g() {return proxy(g_);}
  const_proxy b() const {return const_proxy(b_);}
  proxy b() {return proxy(b_);}

  template <typename From>
  RGB24& operator=(const From& from)
  {
    convert(*this, from);
    return *this;
  }

  uint8_t r_;
  uint8_t g_;
  uint8_t b_;
};

struct RGB565 // 16 bits: MSB | RRRRR GGGGGG BBBBB | LSB
{
  typedef uint16_t data_type;

  typedef channel::Proxy<data_type, 0, 5> b_proxy;
  typedef channel::Proxy<const data_type, 0, 5> const_b_proxy;
  typedef channel::Proxy<data_type, 5, 6> g_proxy;
  typedef channel::Proxy<const data_type, 5, 6> const_g_proxy;
  typedef channel::Proxy<data_type, 11, 5> r_proxy;
  typedef channel::Proxy<const data_type, 11, 5> const_r_proxy;

  RGB565() : data_(0) {}

  template <typename alignment_type = channel::right_aligned_t>
  RGB565(const uint8_t& r_, const uint8_t& g_, const uint8_t& b_, alignment_type = alignment_type())
  {
    alignment_type alignment;
    r().write(r_, alignment);
    g().write(g_, alignment);
    b().write(b_, alignment);
  }

  template <typename From>
  RGB565& operator=(const From& from)
  {
    convert(*this, from);
    return *this;
  }

  const_r_proxy r() const {return const_r_proxy(data_);}
  r_proxy r() {return r_proxy(data_);}
  const_g_proxy g() const {return const_g_proxy(data_);}
  g_proxy g() {return g_proxy(data_);}
  const_b_proxy b() const {return const_b_proxy(data_);}
  b_proxy b() {return b_proxy(data_);}

  data_type data_;
};

typedef bool Monochrome;

template <typename To, typename From>
void convert(To& to, const From& from)
{
  to.r().write(from.r().read(channel::left_aligned), channel::left_aligned);
  to.g().write(from.g().read(channel::left_aligned), channel::left_aligned);
  to.b().write(from.b().read(channel::left_aligned), channel::left_aligned);
}

/* bool to RGB565 wouldn't work without this: */
template <>
void convert<RGB565, Monochrome>(RGB565& to, const Monochrome& from)
{
  to.data_ = from ? 0xFFFF : 0;
}

int main()
{
  cout << "Initializing RGB24 color0(0b11111101, 0, 0)\n\n";
  RGB24 color0(0b11111101, 0, 0);

  cout << "Initializing RGB24 color1(default)\n\n";
  RGB24 color1;

  cout << "color 1 = color0\n";
  color1 = color0;
  cout << "color1.r() = " << std::bitset<8*sizeof(uint8_t)>(color1.r().read(channel::right_aligned)) << "\n";
  cout << "color1.g() = " << std::bitset<8*sizeof(uint8_t)>(color1.g().read(channel::right_aligned)) << "\n";
  cout << "color1.b() = " << std::bitset<8*sizeof(uint8_t)>(color1.b().read(channel::right_aligned)) << "\n\n";

  cout << "Initializing RGB565 color2(0b10001, 0b100100, 0b10100)\n";
  RGB565 color2(0b10001, 0b100100, 0b10100);
  cout << "color2.data = " << std::bitset<8*sizeof(uint16_t)>(color2.data_) << "\n";
  cout << "color2.b(right aligned) = " << std::bitset<8*sizeof(uint8_t)>(color2.b().read(channel::right_aligned)) << "\n";
  cout << "color2.b(left aligned) = " << std::bitset<8*sizeof(uint8_t)>(color2.b().read(channel::left_aligned)) << "\n\n";

  cout << "color 0 = color2\n";
  color0 = color2;
  cout << "color0.b(right aligned) = " << std::bitset<8*sizeof(uint8_t)>(color0.b().read(channel::right_aligned)) << "\n";
  cout << "color0.b(left aligned) = " << std::bitset<8*sizeof(uint8_t)>(color0.b().read(channel::left_aligned)) << "\n\n";

  cout << "Initializing Monochrome color3(true)\n\n";
  Monochrome color3 = true;

  cout << "color 2 = color3\n";
  color2 = color3;
  cout << "color2.data = " << std::bitset<8*sizeof(uint16_t)>(color2.data_) << "\n";
  cout << "color2.b(right aligned) = " << std::bitset<8*sizeof(uint8_t)>(color2.b().read(channel::right_aligned)) << "\n";
  cout << "color2.b(left aligned) = " << std::bitset<8*sizeof(uint8_t)>(color2.b().read(channel::left_aligned)) << "\n\n";

  return 0;
}
```

With this code, converting 1000 pixels from RGB565 to RGB24 takes 296 us with the source pixels generated from ADC noise (the compiler cannot have taken any shortcut here regarding the source data). Converting 1000 pixels from Monochrome to RGB24 takes 313 us, using a template specialization of convert().

Comment: What's wrong with just having a common `Color` interface/base class that they  all implement?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of OOP and hierarchy-based designs, but I'm with Patrick, this is a case well suited by an interface. Are you worried with dynamic-dispatch overhead? **First profile. Then optimize**

Comment: I need this to be highly optimized for use in embedded systems, and I'm not sure (due to lack of expertise) if the compiler (gcc) can do that if I have virtual methods that can be reimplemented by the specific color types.

Comment: Design your interface for bulk operations, to avoid a virtual function call per pixel or similar? Although arguably still premature optimisation.

Comment: It might indeed be possible to get away without pixel-wise operations, but I don't know that yet. Good point, though. OTOH this would rule out drawing algorithms that use a specific color class for painting pixel-wise on a canvas that has a different color type, making it harder to swap canvas color types.

Comment: Do you need to be able to switch implementations at run-time? Or is this a compile-time choice (i.e. solvable using the preprocessor)? And yes, the comparison is not really a fair one, since your direct copy uses the `bool` assignment overload, which is skipped 100% of the time (even branch prediction rules in this case). Even with an always-true pattern, monochrome case is a special case and, if anything, you should concentrate on the 16->24 case where there will be a computation step involved.

Comment: @Groo Which color type is assigned to which other color type is known at compile time. The conversion should not be fixed, though, as I've described in the third use case in the "background" section. Template solutions and specializations, as André has suggested, are absolutely fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, from the question, I see it is required that the solution have very fast execution time, so this requirement should drive the approaches we can try to solve the problem.

This leads to the conclusion that we should avoid virtual function calls on a per pixel basis, otherwise the CPU will have to make one extra unneeded indirection for each pixel. However, we should not avoid virtual functions at all, as it is totally acceptable to use them on per canvas operations.

So, the general solution I propose is to focus on run-time flexibility on canvas classes, so that you can, for instance, use inheritance for each canvas type, and to focus on compile-time binding for pixel operations.

The problem suggests the most important feature to be addressed by the color classes is the conversion of colors formats between them, so I'll focus on that for now. You can implement conversion functions between types using three approaches:

- *Star*: every color format is convertible to and from the most precise format. To convert A into B, first convert A to the most precise format, then from this format to B. This is simple and very extensible, as adding a new format just requires the definition of two more functions, i.e., the number of functions grows linearly with the number of formats (*O(N)*).
- *Fully connected*: every color is convertible to and from every other color format. This is much faster, because requires only one conversion with the minimum effort and maximum potential for optimization. However, the number of functions is *O(N<sup>2</sup>)*.
- *Hybrid*: if a direct conversion is defined, it is used, otherwise, use the most precise format as intermediary.

In order to the compiler to pick the right conversion function, templates are the most elegant solution that I can figure out. I'll try to keep it simple, but of course, this can leads to some limitations.

**Added:** One of the limitations is partial function template specialization, that would actually be useful when some conversion function code applies to more than one pair of formats. A suggested approach to deal with this is to use a traits system to describe a color format. The `convert` function in the code below would be written as a template method in the format traits. This is not covered in this answer.

Let's have some code (**Edited**):

```
// Complete and repeat the class definition below for every color format.
// There is no specific interface to follow, but all classes must have a
// template constructor and a template assignment operator to convert from
// other color formats.
class ColorXYZ {
public:
    ...
    template <class Other>
    ColorXYZ(const Other& other) {
        convert(*this, other);
    }
    template <class Other>
    ColorXYZ& operator=(const Other& other) {
        convert(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }
    ...
};

// These should be class definitions, not just forward declarations:
class ColorMono;
class ColorRGB16;
class ColorRGB24;

// Every format must be able to convert to and from the MostPreciseFormat
typedef ColorRGB24 MostPreciseFormat;

// Generic conversion of color formats that converts to MostPreciseFormat and
// then to the required format.
template <class To, class From>
void convert(To& to, const From& from) {
    MostPreciseFormat precise(from);
    convert(to, precise);
}

// Specialization to convert from Mono to RGB24.
template <>
void convert<ColorRGB24, ColorMono>(ColorRGB24& to, const ColorMono& from) {
    // specific code to convert from mono to RGB24.
    to.setR(from.value() ? 255 : 0);
    to.setG(from.value() ? 255 : 0);
    to.setB(from.value() ? 255 : 0);
}

... // A lot of other specializations of convert here.
```

The compile will pick the most specialized conversion function when it exists, otherwise it should fallback to the conversion that uses `MostPreciseFormat`.

**Added:** It is important that all specializations of `convert` are defined for `MostPreciseFormat` in both `To` and `From`, including the case where that format is the same for `To` and `From`. To be more specific, for the code above, at least the following specializations are needed:

```
convert<ColorRGB24, ColorMono>
convert<ColorRGB24, ColorRGB16>
convert<ColorRGB24, ColorRGB24>
convert<ColorRGB24, ColorXYZ>
convert<ColorMono,  ColorRGB24>
convert<ColorRGB16, ColorRGB24>
convert<ColorRGB24, ColorRGB24>
convert<ColorXYZ,   ColorRGB24>
```

**Added:** Other specializations, such as converting from Mono to RGB16 can use the generic approach, that will be instantiated as a conversion from Mono to RGB24 and from RGB24 to RGB16. This is inefficient (*star* approach), but works. For common cases, it might be a good idea to have specializations too (towards *fully connected* approach).

You should note that there is no common base class between all colors and it shouldn't exist. I expect the user to have a `Canvas` class that abstracts the details of working with every pixel format by means of virtual methods. For instance:

```
class Canvas {
public:
    ...
    virtual void setPixel(unsigned int index, ColorRGB24 color) = 0;
    ...
};

class CanvasMono {
public:
    ...
    virtual void setPixel(unsigned int index, ColorRGB24 color) {
        pixel[index] = color; // converting from RGB24 to mono
    }
    ...
private:
    ColorMono* pixel;
};
```

Depending on most common use cases, it might be worth to have an overload for each format, or at least the most common ones. But if the user shouldn't use formatted color values frequently, there can be only one overload and it always use the `convert` function.

I hope I covered the most relevant aspects of the color system you want to create.

Comment: This looks helpful. I assume the return type of `ColorXYZ::operator=(const Other& other)` should be `ColorXYZ` instead of `Color`, or did I miss a declaration somewher?

Comment: I'm missing an important bit in `MostPreciseFormat`. In the end, `convert` has to assign something to `to`, but I don't see where that might happen. As it is outlined now, it would recurse infinitely. When I implement `MostPreciseFormat::operator=()` using `convert()`, this will not catch the case where no conversion is necessary (when the type of `from` and `to` match).

Comment: I've tried to implement your suggestion (see question), but I'm not sure if that is actually what you meant.

Comment: @Christoph, I've made some mistakes, but I believe I corrected them now. I also added an example when `To` and `From` are the same and filled the body of the sample specialization. The non-specialized version of `convert` should not recurse infinitely if there are specializations of `convert` for all the cases regarding the `MostPreciseFormat`. Please note that the generic version of `convert` should be kept generic, as I did. The code specifying how to convert to and from `MostPreciseFormat` goes on a separated specialization.

Comment: I'm puzzled a bit, because what you describe sound like a partial function specialization for `convert<RGB24, T>()`, which is not possible. So I think I still don't fully understand your concept, but I'll try on

Comment: Sorry, I did write a partial function template specialization actually when I edited the answer to add the case for conversion to the same format. However, that's not the solution core and it is easy to workaround that (using a traits class for format or giving all possible no-op conversions). I'll edit again to make my answer yet more clear and this time I'll pass by a compiler before submitting. Thanks for your patience on trying to understand the mess I did.

Comment: This is not as simple as I hoped, but I accept this as the correct answer now because it outlines the method quite well.

Comment: I've added my current code to the question and some CPU usage measurements. I'm quite satisfied!

Answer (score 1):

Create a Color interface with setter/getter methods

```
class Color {
public:
    void setR(unsigned char )=0;
    unsigned char getR()=0;
    ...
}
```

and inherit it to custom color classes as you want with bitfield data and overridden methods.

```
class RGB556 : public Color {
    unsigned char r:5;
    unsigned char g:5;
    unsigned char b:6;
public:
    void setR(unsigned char  r) { this->r=r; }
    unsigned char getR() { return r; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: OK, I'll implement normal inheritance first and see how much time it takes. If it takes too long, I'll come back.

Comment: It took too long, I'm back! I've added the results of my first test to the question.